# Ubuntu 16 - Problem installing printer driver

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

Problem installing printer driver for Brother HL-3140CW.

Ubuntu 16.04

Brother provides a driver, `hl3140cwcupswrapper-1.1.4-0.i386.deb`. If I try and install it using GDebi package manager it comes up with "dependency is not satisfiable". The same driver worked on my laptop which is running Lubuntu, therefore dependencies ARE satisfiable. It is just that Ubuntu has deleted them from its repository! No indication is given as to what dependencies are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Brother provides an installer tool. I recommend that; from the [Brother - Driver Install Tool](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl3140cw_us_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) page and if you click to download it and SAVE, it should end up in your Downloads folder; the commands to install would be

```
cd Downloads
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz
```

and run the script:

```
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 HL-3140CW
```

Watch the terminal; after a while, it will ask you for device URI: there will be a list of about 12 to choose from: choose what seems best; you can always re-run the script later if needed.